# Activate another extension when SSH extension is active

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I’m developing an extension that activates when a file with a specific extension (.py, .js, etc.) is in the workspace. My extension activates when I am connected to the local workspace within VS Code on my laptop. When I try to connect to my remote workspace using the SSH extension with the files that has the specific file extensions that my extension is looking for, my extension will not activate. How do i fix this issue, is there a specific activation event I should use or something else?

I referenced activation events in VS Code using this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onWebviewPanel

Thanks!

Comment: Your extension must be manually installed on the remote workspace or it won't work. Switch to the extension tab when you open a remote workspace and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works.